# Cannot Change Object Permissions?

Tags: custom-object, permissions

I need to change some custom objects permissions for the `Standard User` profile. But those checkboxes seem read-only. How can I update these permissions?

[image: inline]

Comment: If you are new to Salesforce data security, you should definitely complete the related [Salesforce Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/data_security/units/data_security_objects).

Answer (score 9):

You are limited to the settings that are editable on standard profiles. This includes the Standard User profile, which does not allow you to edit the object level permissions.

You must clone the a standard profile (in this case the Standard User) and then customize your settings with your new Custom Profile.

> Your org includes several **standard profiles** where **you can edit a limited number of settings.**

[See here for more details on **Profiles**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_userprofiles.htm&type=5)

[See here for specific details on **Cloning Profiles**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_cloning.htm&type=5)

Additionally, as **@cropredy** mentioned, you can use **Permission Sets** to add additional permissions if you want to keep the same Standard User profile (**Note: you cannot remove permissions with Permission Sets**).

[See here for details on how to create, manage, and assign **Permission Sets**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/perm_sets_overview.htm)

Comment: or use permission sets

Comment: good call @cropredy , updated answer to include Permission Sets as an option for adding permissions.